# Dynamically Invoke Property in AS3

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, properties

I would like to dynamically invoke a `Class`'s `Property` via a `String`.  In the following code, I can dynamically invoke a `Class`'s `Function` via a `String`.

```
var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("myPackage.MyClass") as Class;
myClass["myStaticMethod"]();
```

where `MyClass` is defined as:

```
package myPackage {
    public class MyClass {
         public function MyClass() {}
         public function myMethod():void {};
         public static function myStaticMethod():void {};
         public static function get myProperty():Object { return null; }
    }
}
```

However, a `Property`, such as `MyClass.myProperty` is not a `Function`.  So,

```
var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("myPackage.MyClass") as Class;
myClass["myProperty"]();
```

throws an error: `TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function` because `myProperty` is not a `Function`.

Is there any way to do this dynamically via `String`s?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, I simply needed to remove the `()` from the code. That is, the new code looks like:

```
var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("myPackage.MyClass") as Class;
myClass["myProperty"]; // This works.
```

Comment: Not sure sure if you already figured this out or needed it but now what you'll have is a Class typed object in your array so you can call new myClass["myProperty"]() to create instances.

Comment: @shaunhusain You mean `new myClass();`

Answer (score 2):

The Answer of Alex will indeed works properly, but only if you have the String written properly. Else you get this error thrown at you: `TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.` To avoid this you could try test if the property or method is defined before using it. Like so:

```
if(myClass["myProperty"] != undefined) 
{
...
}
```

Anyhow, in your specific example you are requesting a getter, and that's why you had to remove the `()` from your source. If you would be needing a method, I would also recommend you to save the method as a function:

```
var myFunction: Function = myClass["theFunction"];
```

And then to use either the `call` or the `apply` methods.

```
myFunction.call(null, myParam);
```

IF you are interested in studying all the methods that an Object has and comparing them to a String. Consider also:

```
var child:Sprite = new Sprite();
var description:XML = describeType(child);
var methodList: XMLList = description.descendants('method');
```

The attributes of a `<method/>` node are:

- **name**: The name of the method.
- **declaredBy**: The class that contains the method definition.
- **returnType**: The data type of the method's return value.

I hope this helps out, let me know if you found it useful.